# How to get files uploaded via multer using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using the below function to get the files uploaded by multer in mongodb.The request is returning empty array.

```
exports.getPhotos = async (req, res) => {

    const photos = await Photo.find()
        .then(photos => {
            res.status(200).json(photos);
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json({message: "Something went wrong"}));
};
```

and this is the schema of the image. Is there any way to get the files without specifying the schema?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema;

const photoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    lenght: {
        type: String,
    },
    chunkSize: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    uploadDate: {
        type: Date,
    },
    filename: {
        type: String,
    },
    md5: {
        type: String,
    },
    contentType: {
        type: String,
    },

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Photo", photoSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use gridfs so it could upload larger files too . a piece of sample code below

```
//Connecting to mongo 
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

//Init gfs 
let gfs; 
conn.once('open', ()=>{
    gfs = GridFsStream(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('uploads');
})
//Creating Storage engine 
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url:mongoURI,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            crypto.randomBytes(16,(err, buf)=>{
                if(err){
                    return reject(err)
                }
                const fileName = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname)
                //bucket name should match the collection name 
                const fileInfo = {
                    filename:fileName,
                    bucketName:'uploads'
                }
                resolve(fileInfo);
            })
        })
    }
})
const upload = multer({storage})
```

now use this upload const in your paths like the one below there are a few methods for upload like array , single and ... depends on number of files you are uploading . the 'uploadedFile' argument is the name of the file input and you should be consider setting it in your frontend.

```
app.post('/',upload.single('uploadedFile'),(req, res)=>{
    res.json('file uploaded')
})
```

this upload middleware adds a files to your request which you can use to put file names in your database and later fetch it by that uniqe names with a route like the one below .

```
app.get('/:filename', (req, res)=>{
    gfs.files.findOne({filename:req.params.filename},(err,file)=>{
        if(!file || file.length === 0){
            return res.status(404).json({
                err:'No file Exists'
            })
        }
            const readStream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
            readStream.pipe(res)
    })
})
```